# Approaches for controlling 20 motors

Tags: microcontroller, communication, motor-controller, digital-communications

I am interested in controlling 20 DC motors. I plan for each motor to have its own motor controller which will do speed and torque control.

I want these motors to all be controlled by a higher level controller which receives current motor state and broadcasts target speeds or torques. The higher level controller will then send the information through USB to a quasi realtime computer.

I want the target states and current states to be broadcasted at 1kHz.

Currently I am focusing on how to approach connecting the motor controllers to the common master MCU. I am not sure which communication protocol I can use to achieve this since none of the common protocols which allow for multiple slaves will sustain the needed data rate.

Bitbanging is a possibility but it will be nontrivial to do right.

What is the correct way to approach this?

Comment: kHz. You need to decide what messages and in what format you want to send out. Then you can estimate a bit rate. Then you can find a bus protocol. Remember, you don't need to necessarily need to poll or handshake the slaves for their data. Nor do you need a protocol with *built in* addressing.

Comment: Being very liberal and ignoring frame stuff, with a 32bit state I need a bit rate of 4 MHz. I could probably cut it to 16 bits making it 2MHz.

Comment: Your controller needs to have limits on acceleration to limit current & Current sensing,  for braking too to minimize overshoot with phase feedback or hall sensing with BLDC control. Depending on power, I would use full bridge BLDC controls with 3 phase for low DC ripple.

Comment: RS-422 can be much faster than that, hardware permitting and can be duplex. Depending on application, no need to poll. Slaves can just listen to their transmission line and when its quiet and/or their turn they can broadcast their state which saves master transmission bandwidth.

Comment: I believe I2C can be run at a higher clock rate than the spec if you're creating the master and the slaves.

Comment: @Drew I2C specs go up to 5 MHz but finding MCUs that support 5 MHz mode is another thing.

Comment: I2C is the last method you’d want to consider! If tight synchronism is required for the motors, then ethercat would be one possible choice.

Comment: You can't control speed and torque simultaneously. If you set a speed, the motor will operate at whatever torque satisfies the torque vs. speed demand curve of the load. Speed and torque set-points or limits rarely need to be updated at a kHz rate.  The needed rates will be determined by the needed acceleration and deceleration rates and by the friction and inertia presented by the loads. I believe this question presents too many issues. This forum is for one concise question per post, not for discussions. I am voting to close.

Comment: The question is pretty concise if you actually read it. I'm asking about the communication protocol not your thoughts on the needed state update rates.